# How to share from Microsoft Word 2013 directly to Gmail

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

I have associated gmail as the default email client when opening mailto: links.

I am wondering if it is possible to share my Word/Powerpoint etc. files directly from the program as an attachment to my Gmail account.

I've tried clicking the *email* option in the *share* menu, but it won't recognize gmail as an email client.

Comment: "I have associated gmail as the default email client when opening mailto: links." - Where did you do this, in your browser? You probably need a desktop email client, such as Outlook or Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Google Desktop Apps which will require Google Chrome. It will allow GMail to appear as an installed application and set to a default mail client for your mailto: links. However, I use a custom domain through Google for serving as my mail server through GMail.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45684